# Laravel seeding date and foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I have some struggles to seed foreign key at this table:

[image]

with this factory:

[image]

and this seeder:

[image]

I usually get this error:

[image]

I have tried to comment those fields at the table and just to make some posts without them and then I get the same error just for the field 'updated_at'.

Any ideas on how to solve this? :D

Thanks!

Comment: share your `App\Models\Post.php`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. Please edit your question, replace your images with actual text code.

Comment: @Don'tPanic it is answered :D I published images because I knew it is something stupid ;) But thanks for the advice

Comment: @apokryfos Read comment above ;) Thanks anyways

Comment: @AkhzarJaved read cooments above ;) Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `asText` for `paragraphs` and `words` to true:

```
$this->faker->paragraphs(3, true)
```

These are methods' signatures:

```
@method array|string words($nb = 3, $asText = false)
@method array|string paragraphs($nb = 3, $asText = false)
```

Comment: Well, this is the answer :D Thanks man I totally forgot about this.